# How to open two terminal windows in IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, pycharm

Is it possible to open two terminal windows in IntelliJ IDEA (or in any other IDE based on it, like PyCharm)?

Comment: Well the embedded terminal support tabs if that's good enough. If you want multiple terminals in one view, then use something like `tmux` ...

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I'd like to see them side by side. Thanks for the tab advice though!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In case of terminal toolbar status, you can do one of these options
[image]

Also after that you can drag them as tabs and let them be side by side.

Comment: Is there any way to get two terminals side-by-side in the same view?  Ie split the terminal window into two side-by-side terminal windows?  VS Code can do this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-splitting  am wondering if Pycharm can.

Comment: @AdamParkin I don't use Pycharm but I don't think be any different between JetBrains tools. After clicking on plus icon and making new tab, then you drag each tab to any other place and let them be side by side.

Answer (score 9):

You can open multiple tabs and then use the mouse drag them out into the editor area. Then you may want to split the editor vertically to have two consoles side by side. Or you could use one terminal in the tool window and the other up in the editor area.

Comment: Is there a way to split the terminals at the bottom? One in the left bottom corner, one in the right bottom, instead of the full width terminal?

Comment: This is what I came here for, and still can't find a solution for this @Janneman96

Comment: I've stopped using IntelliJ as my default editor, I'm using Visual Studio Code now. It happens to have the option to use multiple terminal windows by clicking Terminal>split terminal. The amount of times you can 'split' (add new terminal windows) seems to be only limited by your resolution/screen size.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in **IntelliJ Idea**...

Click the plus icon **to open a second terminal window**

[image: terminal image 1]

If you want to split the windows so both shows at the same time, just right-click on the second tab and select **horizontal or vertical**

[image: terminal image 2]

Hope it helped someone.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I need.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to switch between the views?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Besides the great answer given by avb (using the + or right click), you can of course also use a hotkey for this (when selected the terminal) press:

MacOs: Command+T / ⌘T

Windows / Linux: Ctrl + T

Note: you can even rename tabs by double clicking on their label.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag terminal tabs into editor view and then use standard horizontal/vertical split to position them wherever you want them.

It's a bit hack since the editor then considers your terminal window a file and names it `Local` or `Local(x)` if you have multiple.

Also note, that since IDE considers it a file, you cannot just split the view to get a new instance of terminal. You would have to use the terminal view to create a new tab and then again drag it to the designated area.

This is how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has just been working for me now! (pyCharm CE 2020.1)

1. open any file in the editor.
2. right click the above file's header and split "Horizontally".
3. right click again on the bottom editor window and split "Vertically".
4. open terminal and then open an extra terminal (2 terminals)
5. Right click each terminal and send them to Editor (you need to send each terminal to an active editor.
6. Close the unwanted editors

thats it

Answer (score 1):

Wow,I found that right now, The solution comes from **PyCharm 2016.3 Help**:
Right-click the tab header and choose Change Splitter Orientation on the context menu.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot, please?

Comment: this is completely not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the terminal tab in terminal window before moving. Then, the name is retained instead of "Local"

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 actual windows and not "two views in one window" (so not two next or below each other but separated windows entirely), I could only find one way to 'detach' a terminal from the main console view.

You click on the terminal tab and click "Move to editor". Now it is a separate tab which can be detached from the main editor and placed anywhere you want by dragging the tab with the mouse like usual. Do note that a hotkey "Go to terminal" will go to the main terminal window and not this detached terminal window.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It's not a native solution, but as Bohuslav Burghardt has suggested in his comment, you could use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux). You can split horizontally and vertically as desired.

[Here](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/) is a handy cheat sheet to familiarize yourself with its commands.

For splitting in particular, you can use:

- `Ctrl+b %` to split vertically
- `Ctrl+b "` to split horizontally

And to navigate between your panes, you can use `Ctrl+b` followed by an arrow key.